# Cannot start ruby on rails "start project"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

```
[sanorian@Elliot Ruby]$ sudo rails new blog
      create  
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  .gitattributes
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init -b main from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/sanorian/Documents/Projects/Ruby/blog/.git/
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  Dockerfile
      create  .dockerignore
      create  bin/docker-entrypoint
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_1.rb
      create  config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_1.rb
         run  bundle install
Don't run Bundler as root. Installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 82 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux
Writing lockfile to /home/sanorian/Documents/Projects/Ruby/blog/Gemfile.lock
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  importmap:install
<internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:49:in `init!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:42:in `install!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:34:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:68:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /home/sanorian/Documents/Projects/Ruby/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
<internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:49:in `init!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:42:in `install!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:34:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:68:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /home/sanorian/Documents/Projects/Ruby/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
[sanorian@Elliot blog]$ bin/rails server
<internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:49:in `init!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:42:in `install!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:34:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:68:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /home/sanorian/Documents/Projects/Ruby/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
[sanorian@Elliot blog]$ sudo bin/rails server
<internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:49:in `init!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:42:in `install!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:34:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:68:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /home/sanorian/Documents/Projects/Ruby/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I I'm just trying to learn ruby on rails and ruby and i doesn't know what to do. I uses start project, created by `rails new blog` how it said in official guide
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html . And I cannot run it by `bin/rails server`

Comment: Don't install gems as root (like `bundler` and `rails`). And don't create new Ruby on Rails projects as root. Then running `rails new blog create` (without `sudo`) should work.

Comment: @spickermann This doesn't help. 
still <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
        from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:49:in `init!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-...

Comment: I made this. I added path variables for ruby gem, add `require 'json'` to config/boot.rb and add `gem 'json' to Gemfile

Comment: _"cannot load such file -- json"_ – that's unusual because `json` is one of the [default gems in Ruby 3.0.0](https://stdgems.org/3.0.0/). How did you install Ruby?

Comment: @Stefan: Several "System Rubies" are de-composed into smaller packages, i.e., one package for the VM and the core library, one for documentation, one for the headers, and one package each for each of the standard libraries. That way, Ruby packages can explicitly depend on only the library packages they use, security vulnerabilities in library packages can be fixed without updating the whole thing (e.g. there is no need to update json to fix a vulnerability in net/http), and so on. It makes sense if you use System Ruby as intended (by packaging your apps as .deb or .rpm and declaring your …

Comment: … dependencies), but of course it doesn't work if you don't use it to develop distribution packages.

Comment: Sanorian, how did you install Ruby? Did you use https://rubyinstaller.org/? Or some other solution/tutorial? Please link it so we can take a look

Answer (score 0):

I made this. I added path variables for ruby gem, add require 'json' to config/boot.rb and add `gem 'json' to Gemfile